# Microsoft Word paste modifies text (not formatting!!)?

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste

Using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016, I cut a sentence from Document A and pasted it into Document B. What I didn't expect was Word to be context-aware enough to change the text I pasted.

What I copied from Document A:

- "The blah blah blah blah **PROJECT 1 NAME** blah blah An Acronym Was Here (**AAWH**)"

What was actually pasted into Document B:

- "The blah blah blah blah **PROJECT 2 NAME** blah blah An Acronym Was Here (**AAW**)"

Apparently, Word recognized that the documents were for different projects and changed the name as I pasted it in. How? Did someone set something up in this document to be smart? Also, it messed with the acronym, dropping the last character for some reason, even though the acronym should not have changed at all.

I was blown away by what just happened. I would like to know how it happened so I can repeat it. All my Googling only found items about copy-paste formatting of text, which is not what I'm looking for. I am looking for information on how and why the text itself changed as I pasted it.

Additionally, pasting straight into Notepad I got the exact text from Document A, so it wasn't modified going into the clipboard. It also doesn't change when I copy-paste from Notepad into Word, but only from one Word document into another.

What is this mechanism?

Comment: Are the programs that were changed related to Microsoft?

Comment: @Scorpion99 No, they were project names that were used in the file name of the Word doc. Example: Project Alpha, Project Beta.... I'll remove the word "Program" to disambiguate.

Comment: In excel there is a new option released in 2013 called "Flash Fill", could there be a similar in Word?

Comment: Are there fields in the text you copied (eg referencing bookmarked text or custom document properties) which might contain the name of the project and acronym?

Comment: @Tanya There are fields in the documents. I think it has to do with Content Control, but am not certain.

Comment: In either document, press Alt+F9 and see if those pieces of text change at all.

Comment: @Werrf No, they do not change. Interesting.